# Configure Sendmail to require valid SPF checks before accepting/relaying mail

Tags: sendmail, spf, microsoft-office-365

We have an inbound email service that is very restrictive on who is allowed to send through our Sendmail gateways.  The restrictions are generally controlled through the `access` file by  marking certain servers, IPs or networks as OK -- everything else is rejected.

This method becomes difficult to control when customers are using hosted solutions like Google Apps or Office 365, where mail could come from any number of servers or networks.

In order to get around that, what I would like to add as a feature are SPF checks on certain sender domains.  If their domain passes SPF, then they are allowed to send to us; otherwise the message will be rejected.

It seems there are a [few](http://smfs.sourceforge.net/smf-spf.htmlxQ&sig2=a0Q4JXYHvcyonrUIXbTOkQ) [milters](http://search.cpan.org/~tvierling/Mail-Milter-0.07/lib/Mail/Milter/Module/SPF.pm) out there to handle SPF, but documentation is sparse.

**So the question...**

What options do I have for SPF filtering in Sendmail which can be limited to certain sender domains?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why are they sending THROUGH your servers?

Comment: @symcbean: I think he's asking what SPF milter should he go and try.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I think he refers to the ability provided from certain mail providers to send mail as a user from another domain. If his domain is example.com, then their servers will see incoming mail say from Gmail that claims to be from a user@example.com. They do not seem to allow that.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm pretty sure he's receiving e-mail and just want to eliminate almost all SPAM by only allowing e-mail that Passes SPF. I've considered this myself as most reputable domains publish SPF these days.

Comment: @adamo Further I'm thinking the normally just configure the relevant IPs to allow inbound e-mail, but when it's hosted at Google there'd be a zillion IPs that would have to be allowed and that's inconvenient at best.

Comment: @Chris S: TTBOMK all mail from Gmail comes from *.google.com servers, so he can use the Connect: keyword in the access database.

Comment: @joeqwerty - These are front-end MTA's for another systems which does further automated processing on emails. So yes, they are sent through (e.g. relayed to internal domains).

Comment: @ChrisS, although Connect works for Google, it doesn't for many other hosted mail services.  Also, using Connect, I can't limit certain sender domains through Google - I have to open it up to all of their customers. Not a huge problem, but not ideal.

Comment: Why, having inbound SPF check functionality, would you not want to apply it to all sent emails?  You seem to be making your usage case much more difficult by adding that restriction, and it makes no sense: the only disadvantage to checking SPF on **all** inbound mail is the time required to set SPF checking up, and you're proposing todo that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is [spfmilter](http://www.acme.com/software/spfmilter/) and [milter-spiff](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-spiff/) just to name two. And milter-spiff's documentation is far from sparse. We're using for many years now without any problems.

Comment: So some of the relevant configuration files/example/documentation would be???

Comment: The documentation page for milter-spiff is [here](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-spiff/). You can run "milter-spiff -help" and it will output a very well commented configuration file which you can save, edit and use afterwards.

Comment: milter-spiff seems to be what I need.  I will need to spend some time testing.

Comment: It appears that both of these only do blanket SPF filtering, and I cannot limit the checks to certain sender domains.

Comment: The you can install [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) along with [Mail::SPF::Query](http://search.cpan.org/~jmehnle/Mail-SPF-Query-1.999.1/lib/Mail/SPF/Query.pm) and write your own custom sets within the [filter_recipient](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) routine.